# Calling a method on Parent Component from Child Component

Tags: reactjs

The project I am working on has a NotificationHeader component which has the infra for showing notifications. Specifically, it has a method

```
addNotification(msg,type)   {
  console.log('addNotification.this:%O',this);
  // rest of the method to show notification. 
}
```

The rest of the components on the page are children to this NotificationHeader component. I am passing the addNotification method down to the children as props, so that I can call it from them.

The issue I am facing is that when I call the addNotification method from the child, the reference to this inside the addNotification is not pointing to the NotificationHeader component, but to addNotification.

[image: Image of the error in js console]

The other examples that I have seen for calling a parent component method from child do not seem to face this issue.

I must mention that since the project uses React router, to pass the addNotification method down to the children I am using React.cloneElement as follows:

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    addNotification: this.addNotification,
})}
```

How can I get this to refer to the NotificationHeader component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should pass down `addNotification` method with bound context. You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to do this:

```
<SomeChildComponent addNotification={this.addNotification.bind(this)} />
```

or if you clone component as you mentioned:

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    addNotification: this.addNotification.bind(this)
})}
```